# Basic ways to optimize this query?

Tags: oracle, optimization

title pretty much says it all. I wrote this big, ugly query that works...however it takes forever to run. I have no experience whatsoever with optimizing SQL, and am pretty new to the language and its functions. I realize none of you will be familiar with the environment I am working in, but I was just wondering if any basic things jump out at you about it. Thanks!

```
SELECT MAX(INVOICE.invoice_id) invoice_id, MAX(invoice.vendor_num) vendor_num, max(invoice.vendor_name) vendor_name,
MAX(invoice.po_number) po_number, MAX(invoice.invoice_date) invoice_date, MAX(invoice.invoice_num) invoice_num,
MAX(invoice.terms_name) terms_name, MAX(invoice.invoice_amount) invoice_amount, MAX(invoice.amount_applicable_to_discount) amount_applicable_to_discount,
MAX(invoice.amount_paid) amount_paid, MAX(invoice.payment_date) payment_date, MAX(invoice.document_id) document_id, 
MAX(invoice.filename) filename,
STAMPS.page_markups_view_id, STAMPS.TEXT, STAMPS.TOOL_NAME 
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT    inv.invoice_id, 
                    vendor.segment1 vendor_num, 
                    vendor.vendor_name, 
                    MAX(poh.segment1) po_number, 
                    inv.invoice_date, 
                    inv.invoice_num, 
                    terms.name terms_name, 
                    inv.invoice_amount, 
                    inv.amount_applicable_to_discount, 
                    inv.amount_paid, 
                    pmt.check_date payment_date,
                    path.document_id, 
                    vendor.segment1 || '-' || inv.invoice_num || '.pdf' filename
    FROM            apps.ap_invoices_all inv, 
                    apps.ap_invoice_distributions_all dist, 
                    apps.po_distributions_all podi, 
                    apps.ap_invoice_payment_history_v pmt, 
                    apps.fnd_attached_docs_form_vl fnd, 
                    markview.mv_page_image_paths path, 
                    apps.po_vendors vendor, 
                    apps.po_headers_all poh, 
                    apps.ap_terms terms 
    WHERE           inv.invoice_id = to_number(fnd.pk1_value) 
    AND             inv.invoice_id = dist.invoice_id 
    AND             poh.po_header_id(+) = podi.po_header_id 
    AND             podi.po_distribution_id(+) = dist.po_distribution_id 
    AND             fnd.file_name = to_char(path.document_id) 
    AND             inv.invoice_id = pmt.invoice_id 
    AND             fnd.category_description = 'MarkView Document' 
    AND             fnd.entity_name = 'AP_INVOICES' 
    AND             inv.vendor_id = poh.vendor_id(+) 
    AND             inv.terms_id = terms.term_id 
    AND             inv.vendor_id = vendor.vendor_id 
    AND             path.platform_name = 'UNIX_FS_TO_DOC_SERVER' 
    AND             pmt.void = 'N'
    and             inv.invoice_id = 1908784
    GROUP BY
    inv.invoice_id, 
    vendor.segment1 , 
    vendor.vendor_name, 
    inv.invoice_date, 
    inv.invoice_num, 
    terms.name , 
    inv.invoice_amount, 
    inv.amount_applicable_to_discount, 
    inv.amount_paid,
    path.document_id, 
    pmt.check_date, 
    vendor.segment1 || '-' || inv.invoice_num || '.pdf'
    ) INVOICE,
    (      SELECT mp.document_id, 
                  moi.markup_object_id, 
                  moi.page_markups_view_id, 
                  moi.text, 
                  mvt.tool_name, 
                  mp.page_id 
           FROM   markview.mv_markup_object moi, 
                  markview.mv_tool mvt, 
                  markview.mv_page_markups_view mpmv, 
                  markview.mv_page mp 
           WHERE  moi.tool_id = mvt.tool_id 
           AND    mp.page_id = mpmv.page_id 
           AND    mpmv.page_markups_view_id = moi.page_markups_view_id 
           AND    mvt.tool_id IN 
                  ( 
                         SELECT mvt.tool_id 
                         FROM   markview.mv_tool 
                         WHERE  mvt.tool_name IN ( 'Green Text', 
                                                  'Blue Sticky Note' ) )) STAMPS
WHERE invoice.document_id = stamps.document_id(+)
GROUP BY 
page_markups_view_id, TEXT, TOOL_NAME
)
```

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: basic tips are add index. start small and go adding part and check the explain analyze to see what is slowing the query, then add more index if need it.

Comment: What do you mean by "the query... works"? I suppose it compiles and it executes OK, but does it produce the correct output? And if so, is that just by accident? In each group it selects, for example, `max(invoice_id)` and `max(vendor_num)` - even though in the base data it is possible that that invoice id is for a DIFFERENT vendor (and if the max invoice id is for the max vendor num, that would just be pure coincidence in most cases). So - before looking for optimization, let's make sure the output is correct; otherwise you will still get bad output, just a lot faster.